# Connect a voice call to a tokbox video call

Tags: call, voice, tokbox

How can I connect dial-in calls to a TokBox video conference?

Comment: hi, interesting, this might be of interest https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/sip/

Comment: Thanks, IronMan! So I need to get a Vonage conference number first, then call that number via SIP URI from TokBox? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: It might be worth trying some code and showing that here - this feels rather broad at the moment, and thus it will be harder for readers to help you.